# Openshift hot_deploy marker is ignored

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have a custom nodejs-0.10 app on Openshift (from here: https://github.com/engineersamuel/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs).  Several months ago I added the hot_deploy marker to my repo as outlined here: https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1057-how-can-i-deploy-my-application-without-having-to-restart-it.

It appeared to work great for awhile, but I've noticed recently it has stopped working.  On deploy, I now see a

`Stopping NodeJS cartridge`

message in the output.  In order to hot deploy now, I have to manually add the --hot-deploy parameter to the "rhc deploy" command.

Here is my marker:

```
ls -l .openshift/markers/
```

`total 0`
`-rwxr-xr-x  1 xxxxxxx  staff  0 May 21 19:54 hot_deploy`

Why is my marker being ignored now?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that is a custom node.js cartridge, have you tried this with the default node.js cartridge that openshift supplies?  You might try posting an issue on the github project and have the creator look into it, as that is not an official OpenShift maintained cartridge.